# Python-wand: How can I read image properties/statistics

Tags: python, image-processing, statistics, imagemagick, wand

I am trying to extract statistics for an image such as the "mean", "standard-deviation" etc.
However, I cannot find anything related in the python-wand documentation about it.

From the command line I can get such statistics like this:

```
convert MyImage.jpg -format '%[standard-deviation], %[mean], %[max], %[min]' info:
```

or

```
convert MyImage.jpg -verbose info:
```

How to get such info from a python program using wand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) doesn't support any of the statistic methods from ImageMagick's C-API (outside of [histogram](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/whatsnew/0.3.html#histogram) and [EXIF](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/guide/exif.html)). Luckily the [wand.api](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/wand/api.html) is offered for extending functionality.

1. Find the [method you need](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickGetImageChannelStatistics) in MagickWand's documentation.
2. Use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to implement data types/structures ([reference header `.h` files](https://subversion.imagemagick.org/subversion/ImageMagick/branches/ImageMagick-6.8.9/magick/statistic.h))

```py
from wand.api import library
import ctypes

class ChannelStatistics(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('depth', ctypes.c_size_t),
                ('minima', ctypes.c_double),
                ('maxima', ctypes.c_double),
                ('sum', ctypes.c_double),
                ('sum_squared', ctypes.c_double),
                ('sum_cubed', ctypes.c_double),
                ('sum_fourth_power', ctypes.c_double),
                ('mean', ctypes.c_double),
                ('variance', ctypes.c_double),
                ('standard_deviation', ctypes.c_double),
                ('kurtosis', ctypes.c_double),
                ('skewness', ctypes.c_double)]

library.MagickGetImageChannelStatistics.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
library.MagickGetImageChannelStatistics.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ChannelStatistics)
```

3. Extend `wand.image.Image`, and use the newly supported methods.

```py
from wand.image import Image

class MyStatisticsImage(Image):
    def my_statistics(self):
        """Calculate & return tuple of stddev, mean, max, & min."""
        s = library.MagickGetImageChannelStatistics(self.wand)
        # See enum ChannelType in magick-type.h
        CompositeChannels = 0x002F
        return (s[CompositeChannels].standard_deviation,
                s[CompositeChannels].mean,
                s[CompositeChannels].maxima,
                s[CompositeChannels].minima)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already implemented something similar :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to anyone following the excellent suggestion by @emcconville:

1. The documentation on the imagemagick site is for v7.x
2. Wand will only work with imagemagick 6.x
3. In IM6.x, there is actually one more field on the end of _ChannelStatistics, a double called entropy, and if you leave it out of your ChannelStatistics declaration your structure won't align properly with what you get back and it'll contain a bunch of nonsense